# Removing extra information of gregexpr in R

Tags: r

I am trying to read a CSV file in R and find particular pattern from a column of file and calculate how many times it appears. Here is the code:

```
dataframe <- read.csv("path-analysis-2003-a.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

for(i in 1:nrow(dataframe))
{
  counter <- gregexpr("-",dataframe$Path[i], fixed = TRUE, useBytes = TRUE)
  print(length(counter))

}
```

However the output shows length is 1 for every row. When I debug the code I found this output:

```
[[1]]
 [1] 10 19 28 41 43 44 45 46 50 60 67
attr(,"match.length")
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

The first line of the output (where location is given) is useful as I can calculate the occurrence from there. However the problem is I am not sure how to get rid of other output information. Any suggestion please?

Comment: `attributes(counter[[1]]) <- NULL`, or more simply `c(counter[[1]])`

Comment: Thanks for that. Could you please explain how it works?

Comment: It's explained in `help(gregexpr)` and `help(attributes)`.

Comment: `unlist(counter)` can also be used

Comment: you also don't need `for` loop, simply write `counter <- gregexpr("-",dataframe$Path, fixed = TRUE, useBytes = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

Following is an example that you can follow. I have added comments to the code to make it self explanatory. The example shows searching for the word stop in the dataframe containing  4 sentences.

```
# some data for the demo
text <- c("Because I could not stop for Death -",
"He kindly stopped for me -",
"The Carriage held but just Ourselves -",
"and Immortality")
# populate sample dataframe
df_sample <- data.frame(id=1:4, sentence=text)
# apply gregexpr, note the function is vectorized no need of loop
result <- gregexpr("stop", df_sample$sentence)
# unlist result to obtain the indices
final <- unlist(result)
# print results
final
```